# JSP Server, "faces" keyword is coming up in the title which is annoying every time

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jsp

I created a Java Project  in JSP. I then added a JSP page in the WebContent folder called home.jsp. I perform on home.jsp:

Right click --> Run As --> Run on server

The web page displays an error.

The URL is : /futurevoicedetails/faces/home.jsp

When i remove the /faces : /futurevoicedetails/home.jsp

The page displays. My question is where has the /faces came from. I have not added any code to this program which makes me assume it is a server or eclipse error. I am using Eclipse Luna. Has anyone had this problem before and if so, what is the solution? It is very annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annoying "faces" seems to be coming from default facesServlet path. I think  jsf facet is enabled for your project.

**Solution ::**
project>>RightClick>>properties>>ProjectFacets>> disable Jsf module there.

Its been long time since I have used jsf ,so this might not work ..but I am sure that jsf is in the root of your problem